# How to make label text right aligned in visual studio?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio, WinForms, I want to make the text of the label aligned to the right. I have used the property `RightToLeft = Yes`, but the problem as follows occur:
The label `Name :` becomes `: Name` after the property `RightToLeft = Yes` is made.
But I want to right aligned the label as `Name :`

Is there anyway to do so? Please help... I am using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [TextAlign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.textalign.aspx) property, not the RightToLeft property. The latter is used for localization to right-to-left languages.

Comment: I used theat property in default label component of visual studio. But I was using some other component so there was not the text align property so it makes me confuse. Anyway thanks...

Comment: CodeNaked is correct but you might find that the container in which your text is being aligned isn't actually as wide as you expect. Add a border around it to see.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, disable AutoSize, then use TextAlign property to set alignment.
It won´t work with AutoSize enabled because it "auto-sizes" starting by left.